# How to trigger ngSubmit without button tag in the form?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to post the user rating (out of 5) to an API but the onSubmit function is not being triggered when I'm using the anchor tag. What can I do to trigger it as it does in the case of button ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUqDx.png

```
<form #f="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="success-banner__right">
   <div class="rating-scale success-banner__ratingBox" name="courseExperience" 
  ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="courseExperience" required #courseExperienceControl="ngModel">
   <h3 class="montserrat-semibold font-16 mg-b20">Rate your Experience</h3>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="courseExperience=1" [class.rating- 
scale__active]="courseExperience>0"><i class="icon-favorite-star"></i></a>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="courseExperience=2" [class.rating- 
scale__active]="courseExperience>1"><i class="icon-favorite-star"></i></a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="courseExperience=3" [class.rating- 
 scale__active]="courseExperience>2"><i class="icon-favorite-star"></i></a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="courseExperience=4"[class.rating- 
 scale__active]="courseExperience>3"><i class="icon-favorite-star"></i></a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="courseExperience=5" [class.rating- 
  scale__active]="courseExperience>4"><i class="icon-favorite-star"></i></a>
 </div>
   </div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try instead of `(click)="courseExperience=1", to (click)="onSubmit(ourseExperience=1)"`. Make sure you change onSubmit() method to receive your "ourseExperience=1"